# Integration of natural logarithm

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

It is a very basic question however the sources through which I am studying are not complete hence I need a little help. How does this
$$\int \frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^2}$$
Turn into this 
$$-\frac1 2 \ln(1-2v-v^2) $$

Comment: Hint: the numerator is proportional to minus the derivative of the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a standard exploitation of a more or less general rule
$$ \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = \log x$$
Of course there are cases when the rule fails (when $f(x)$ is zero,  for instance), but is an essential tool in integration.

It can be verified by evaluating the derivative,
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \log f(x) $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**
$$\int \frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^2}\text{d}v=-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{-2-2v}{1-2v-v^2} \text{d}v$$